# DNA Pairing challenge

Tags: javascript

I was trying to solve the DNA Pairing challenge with the filter method.But somewhere I am missing something. What I am missing?

**Description of challenge:**

1. The DNA strand is missing the pairing element.
2. Take each character, get its pair, and return the results as a 2d
   array.
3. Base pairs are a pair of AT and CG.
4. Match the missing element to the provided character.
5. Return the provided character as the first element in each array.

For example, for the input GCG, it should return `[["G", "C"], ["C","G"], ["G", "C"]]`

```js
    let arr = [];
    
    function pairElement(str) {
      let test = str.split("");
      return test.filter((element) => {
        arr.push(pairElementDna(element));
        console.log(arr);
        return arr;
      });
    
      function pairElementDna(character) {
        let arr = [];
    
        if (character === "G") {
          arr.push(character, "C");
        }
        if (character === "C") {
          arr.push(character, "G");
        }
        if (character === "A") {
          arr.push(character, "T");
        }
        if (character === "T") {
          arr.push(character, "A");
        }
        return arr;
      }
    }
    
    console.log(pairElement("GCG"));
```

Comment: Hi there! Please [edit] your question and include a description of the challenge you're trying to solve and a link to it.

Comment: how does this challenge work? as in why should `GCG` return `[["G", "C"], ["C","G"], ["G", "C"]]`?

Comment: I assume that every letter should be paired with its opposite. A's opposite is T, G's opposite is C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing add the `return arr;` statement end of code blocks and I used global variables instead of using local variables which the array I define at the top `let arr= [];`.

```js
function pairElement(str) {
  let arr = [];

  let test = str.split("");
  test.filter((element) => {
    arr.push(pairElementDna(element));
    return arr;
  });
  function pairElementDna(character) {
    let arr = [];

    if (character === "G") {
      arr.push(character, "C");
    }
    if (character === "C") {
      arr.push(character, "G");
    }
    if (character === "A") {
      arr.push(character, "T");
    }
    if (character === "T") {
      arr.push(character, "A");
    }
    return arr;
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(pairElement("ATCGA"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is overly complicated, is there a reason you a trying to do it with filter?

`Array.filter` returns a shallow copy of the array with elements removed based on the "truthiness" of the value returned from the callback. You always return a truthy value so, nothing gets removed.

You are mapping single characters to arrays of pairs. Try and keep it simple with the appropriate array function: Array.map! Much easier to read.

```js
const dnaPairs = {
  "G": "C",
  "C": "G",
  "A": "T",
  "T": "A"
};

function pairElements(elements) {
  return elements.split("").map(ch => [ch, dnaPairs[ch]]);
}

// log the stringified result as it's easier to read.
console.log(JSON.stringify(pairElements("GCG")));
```

**Fixing Your Code**

It looks like you're using `filter` instead of using a loop. Please don't do this, it makes the code much more difficult to read and understand as this is not what `filter` is for.

That being said, your code almost "works", you are logging the filtered copy of your source array (the result of `filter`) not the array that you build up inside the loop (`arr`). Here's the "fixed" version.

```js
let arr = [];

function pairElement(str) {
  let test = str.split("");
  let filteredResult = test.filter((element) => {
    arr.push(pairElementDna(element));
    //console.log(arr);
    return arr;
  });

  console.log(arr);
  return filteredResult;

  function pairElementDna(character) {
    let arr = [];

    if (character === "G") {
      arr.push(character, "C");
    }
    if (character === "C") {
      arr.push(character, "G");
    }
    if (character === "A") {
      arr.push(character, "T");
    }
    if (character === "T") {
      arr.push(character, "A");
    }
    return arr;
  }
}

pairElement("GCG")
```

**UPDATE** added logging of result to `pairElement` function as requested to by OP in comments

Comment: Thanks for the great explaining, may I know is it possible to call just the pairElement("GCG") function with arguments to see the console output as expected?
Note:I know to do with map but I am wonderingly to know why it is not working with filter method.

Comment: Yes, instead of returning the value directly save the result of map to a variable first, console.log that variable then return the variable.

Comment: Why doesn't it work with filter? That's not what filter does or is for. Do not use filter just because you wanted to try, it's not appropriate for what you are trying to achieve, you'd be better just using a regular for loop.

Comment: I was asked is it possible to call directly just pairElement("GCG")  for the first solution (filter method)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Should you, no!

Comment: Updated my answer - please don't use filter for this purpose though. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but I was looking for something different via your reply I find what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function pairElement(str) {
      const result=[]
      for(let i= 0; i<str.length;i++)
        result.push([str[i]])
      for(let k = 0; k < str.length; k ++){
        if(str[k] == "G"){
          result[k].push("C")
        }
        if(str[k] == "C"){
          result[k].push("G")
        }
        if(str[k] == "A"){
          result[k].push("T")
        }
        if(str[k] == "T"){
          result[k].push("A")
        }

      }

        return result;
    }

    console.log(pairElement("ACGT"));
```